# y_label in matplotlib is cutoff

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot this figure :
[image]

With this :

```
r_bt.longueur_groupby_section.plot(kind='barh',ylabel='Nombre de clients',xlabel='type de cable',title='longueur de conducteur en fonction de la section')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

But the ylabel is cut off..
I tried `plt.autoscale()` but it does not work..

Does anybody have an idea ?

Comment: You are not allowed to enlarge the figure size?

Comment: I can but it won't be a good solution. As I will need to reduce the size after the size of the text will be too small.

Comment: Mh, ok. The only thing i can think of is maybe put some spaces in front of the y axis thicks or give them some rotation with: plt.yticks(rotation = 45)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the spacing around matplotlib figures using the subplots_adjust() function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(whatever)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9, bottom=0.1)
```

increase the left value as per your need